# What are effects of large amout of data in browser, if any

Tags: javascript, browser

Are there any repercussions from having large amounts of data in the browser?

- any memory limits?
- will there be any degraded performance of any type?

I am not worried about effects of manipulating the data.

Another way to ask this is, if I am not concerned with download effects, should I download all data from the server that may ever be needed, or is there a reason not to?

UPDATE:
What I am concerned about are the size of javascript objects.
So I guess the question refers to browser memory as Eric mentions.

App is for in-house use, so bandwidth not an issue.

BTW : How am I to learn, when the question gets downvoted without an explanation?

Comment: more than the memory, you should be concerned about bandwidth and network latency.

Comment: iphone was only 10MB for a long time... on desktops, data is not a bug problem, but many html elements are, so it depends on how you store everything. in short, the answer is like so many other questions related to the web: "it depends".

Comment: @dandavis The data I worry about is in javascript objects.

Comment: you should be able to handle half a gig in chrome, use chrome's task manager to test how many straws break its back.

Comment: @dandavis: That is not a responsible approach for an app to take, unless it is running on a dedicated machine.  It is a huge waste of resources in a multi-tasking environment to allocate half a gig of data I may or may not need.

Comment: @EricJ. OP said this is for internal use. even a cheap computer comes with several gigs of RAM these days. if half a gig of ram saves 100mb of traffic a hour, then running the page for 5 hours pays for itself. i'll concede cache strategy is never clear cut and depends on usage and conditions, but to categorically label it a huge waste is assumptive about several unknown criteria.

Comment: @dandavis: Internal use is different than a dedicated machine.  Half a gig will not *save* anything, assuming he doesn't keep discarding data he already fetched.  Lacking specifics, it is far better to default to "don't load everything you might possibly need into RAM" than taking the opposite position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> any memory limits?

Yes, each browser has its own limits (that may or may not be near the size of data you are talking about, but see @dandavis's comment).

> will there be any degraded performance of any type?

Yes, there is a cost to retrieve the data (latency for each connection, download time, maximum concurrent http(s) connections).  There is also a cost if you fill available memory and/or cache.

> Another way to ask this is, if I am not concerned with download effects, should I download all data from the server that may ever be needed, or is there a reason not to?

Every browser has a limit to what it will cache.  If you download resources that may not be needed, you may evict resources that are needed from the cache (resources of your own website, or resources of other websites the user has visited).

Comment: So javascript objects will be cached? (downloaded via AJAX)

Comment: JavaScript code will be.  JavaScript objects will consume browser memory.  Images, videos, etc will be cached (by most browsers).